# Basic HTML - Unordered List, how to make it my images vertical?

Tags: html, image, list

I have two images and would like to place one on top of another using a list.
The current code I'm using places the second image to the right of the first one, not directly below it.

Any ideas? Might be basic but I'm new to programming. Thanks.

```
<ul>
<li>
<img width="178" height="178" alt="ZE40" src="images/ze40.jpg">
<img width="178" height="40" alt="ZE40" src="images/ze40i.jpg">
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You'll need to show us your CSS. And what you posted is an **un**ordered list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use another `<li></li>` for the second image

```
<ul>
<li>
<img width="178" height="178" alt="ZE40" src="images/ze40.jpg">
</li>
    <li>
        <img width="178" height="40" alt="ZE40" src="images/ze40i.jpg">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Edit: When you use 2 images on 1 `<li>`, it would put 2 images next to each other, but when you use the second, the first one will go on top of the second one just like when you make a list for yourself on a paper.

Comment: Azertit, thats worked thanks. Because they are both images, theres a gap inbetween them, is there a way to get rid of this so both images are touching? thanks for your help.

Comment: you can use negative margin, look at this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1cwudL52/

Answer (score 2):

There are two basic options here:

1. Change the CSS display property for the images to block. **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/aqqo86ng/)**

```
img {
    display:block;
}
```

2. Put each image in its own list item and set the vertical alignment to top. [**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4yghcfh8/):

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <img width="178" height="178" alt="ZE40" src="images/ze40.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img width="178" height="40" alt="ZE40" src="images/ze40i.jpg" />
    </li>
</ul>
img {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <img width="178" height="178" alt="ZE40" src="images/ze40.jpg">

    </li>
    <li>
        <img width="178" height="40" alt="ZE40" src="images/ze40i.jpg">
    </li>
</ul>
```

To remove the space between them you can do this in your CSS:

```
ul, li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```